# Dynamic Memory vs Predetermined Memory

Tags: java, memory, dynamic, linked-list

In class we are learning about linked list and I do not know much about Dynamic memory and Predetermined memory. Where is the data located? what is the performance difference? and how does the memory look?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store, for example, 10 items, you could do it one of two (or many other) ways....

1. Store the items sequentially in memory, like a normal array. The advantage is it's very quick to reach any offset (multiply the data size by the offset), but the size is not flexible. If you then want 11 items, it's not simple to place it at the end (that memory may be something else important).
2. Store them in different parts of memory, but have each item know where to find the next (and sometimes the previous). This means you don't need to know a size up front, but it means reaching any offset means the chain of links must be followed. This is known as a linked list.

Answer (score 0):

[At the risk of oversimplification and underlying system assumptions]

Dynamic memory comes from the application heap. The heap consists of one or more blocks of memory managed by a library. The library allocates pages of memory from the operating system to create the heap.

The dynamic data allocated from the heap could be located almost anywhere within the process address space..

There is a performance hit to allocate data from the heap. The extent of that depends upon the amount of data allocated, state of the heap, algorithm used by the library, and the frequency of allocation. Generally, we live with the performance hit of dynamic memory.

(I'd go into more detail but do not want to overwhelm you.)

The memory looks like any other read/write memory in the system. However, there is usually a hidden header placed before the memory returned to the application. There is often a trailer as well (used to detect overruns).